# Unexplainable transformation of a fraction with complex number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

While solving a cubic equation I came across a "simplification" of a fraction with a complex number that I really can't understand. The thing I can not understand is how the value from the right side of the "=" has the same value.  Image of the equation below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $z_1 = r(\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha)$ and $z_2=s(\cos\beta+i\sin\beta)$, then
$$
\frac{z_1}{z_2}=\frac{r}{s}(\cos(\alpha-\beta)+i\sin(\alpha-\beta)).
$$

So
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{12}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{12}\right)}&=
\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\cos\left(-\frac{\pi}{12}\right)+i\sin\left(-\frac{\pi}{12}\right)\right)\\
&=\sqrt{2}\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{12}-i\sin\frac{\pi}{12}\right).
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Another way to see this is to multiply the numerator and denominator of the fraction by the complex conjugate of the denominator. I will substitute $\alpha = \frac{\pi}{12}$ and in fact the equation holds true for any $\alpha$.

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}\left(\cos\alpha + i\sin\alpha\right)} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{\cos\alpha + i\sin\alpha}\frac{\cos\alpha - i\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha - i\sin\alpha} = \sqrt{2}\frac{\cos\alpha - i\sin\alpha}{\left(\cos\alpha + i\sin\alpha\right)\left(\cos\alpha - i\sin\alpha\right)}$$

$$= \sqrt{2}\frac{\cos\alpha - i\sin\alpha}{\cos^2\alpha + \sin^2\alpha} = \sqrt{2}\frac{\cos\alpha - i\sin\alpha}{1}$$

$$ = \sqrt{2}\left(\cos\alpha - i\sin\alpha\right)$$

where I used the fundamental trigonometric identity $$\cos^2\alpha + \sin^2\alpha = 1$$ valid for any $\alpha$.

---

As an additional remark, the function $$\text{cis}(\alpha) = \cos\alpha + i\sin\alpha$$ satisfies the famous identity of Euler's formula:

$$\cos\alpha + i\sin\alpha = e^{i\alpha}$$

which can be proven by Taylor series expansions (amongst other ways).

From this relationship it is clear that $$\frac{1}{\cos\alpha + i\sin\alpha} = e^{-i\alpha} = \cos(-\alpha) + i\sin(-\alpha) = \cos\alpha - i\sin\alpha$$

Comment: I did not realize the question was 5 years old, it just showed up on my feed today,  sorry if this caused a useless bump.